# Pretty URL for Perl CGI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, perl, cgi

I just converted over from using PHP to Perl for a script that hosts API commands.

As php, the .htaccess looked like:

```
RewriteRule ^api/?$ api.php [L]
RewriteRule ^api/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})?/?$ api.php?command=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})?/?$ api.php?command=$1&key=$2 [QSA,L]
```

End result was executing with a url like `http://example.com/api/command/key` (where api is the script name), worked as intended.

Switching over to Perl, visiting `http://example.com/api` redirects to `http://example.com/usr/lib/cgi-bin/api.pl` which doesn't work in the slightest, and also looks hideous. I've tried everything I can think of with `.htaccess` and `serve-cgi-bin.conf`, but nothing works for me. It doesn't really matter which folder I need to put the `api.pl` in, as long as the folder name and extension don't appear in the url.

How can I get the desired url?

Comment: Is there a reason you decided to go from PHP as CGI to Perl as CGI, which is even older technology? Perl's CGI module has been deprecated and removed from the core installation of current Perl versions. Unless you are on a shared hosting environment that doesn't allow you to open up ports, I would suggest to look into a more modern Plack based solution with Perl. Dancer2 or Mojolicious come to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only need to replace the `api.php` with `cgi-bin/api.pl` in your rules.

```
RewriteRule ^api/?$ cgi-bin/api.pl [L]
RewriteRule ^api/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})?/?$ cgi-bin/api.pl?command=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})?/?([a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,})?/?$ cgi-bin/api.pl?command=$1&key=$2 [QSA,L]
```

You can use a tool like [htaccess.madewithlove.be](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=5f482829-3c6b-57a1-bf36-574ee887ac06) to test your rules.

Comment: If that worked, I wouldn't be posting here :) That was the very first thing I tried. It redirects to http://example.com/usr/lib/cgi-bin/api.pl

Comment: Then your server is not configured properly @derek.

Comment: You were right. Reinstalling apache resolved it. Thanks